# Windows 8.1 Enterprise Sysprep Error

Tags: windows-8, sysprep

I am Trying to sysprep my WIndows 8.1 enterprise (MSDN) and i get the following errors

I have upgraded the Windows 8 to windows 8.1 and the machine contains all the configuration for VS 2012 and rest

Exact error
Sysprep was not able to validate your windows installation

Error msg line in log

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x8007139f
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x139f
# for hex 0x139f / decimal 5023
  ERROR_INVALID_STATE                                            winerror.h
# The group or resource is not in the correct state to
# perform the requested operation.
# 1 matches found for "0x8007139f"
```

SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetValue: Error from RegQueryValueEx on value SysprepMode under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep; dwRet = 0x2

I have searched the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep

But i coud'nt find anything for SYSprep mode

The value for sysprep was (Value not set)

Comment: looks like you're the same users who asked this on Technet. Have you looked for a value called **SysprepMode** in the registry?

Comment: I have searchedHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep 

But i coud'nt find anything for SYSprep mode 

The value for sysprep was (Value not set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the sysprep to work

You need to take care of the following things

A> It doesn't work with upgraded PC

B> For fresh installation and creating sysprep you need to activate the administrator account delete any other user account

C> Don't update any of the metro apps. Normal windows update is fine .

D> If you need to add any other settings please use the answer file settings.

Tested with Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Comment: I've successfully gotten a system to sysprep and capture into WDS after an upgrade. Just delete the registry DWORD HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade.  Don't worry if it is a 0, just the mere presence of this value prevents sysprep from running.  Also, make sure you delete c:\windows.old and the c:\Windows~BT folders or your image will not be able to deploy due to conflicts.