# Sysprep was not able to validate your Windows installation (Win10 x64 1809)

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, sysprep

Sysprep from Win10 x64 ver 1809 fails with an error message, and after checking 16 suggestions, I ask for assistance.

> Sysprep was not able to validate your Windows installation

[image: Error message from Sysprep]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n_G7_9baHMNmhwWAWKUolW5T5NMnhAsf lists the 24 errors found in [%WINDIR%\System32\Sysprep\Panther\setupact.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14zU8aYW01ZNIBIztqJMBTXr0mKHfApDI/view?usp=sharing) when I tried to install Windows 10 version 1809 on a new desktop machine, a PC which installs flawlessly with Windows 10 1709.

[https://superuser.com/questions/1238880/sysprep-was-not-able-to-validate-windows-installation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769827/sysprep-fails-after-you-remove-or-update-windows-store-apps-that-inclu) suggested four things which did not work:

a) reviewing the Remaining Windows rearm count w/ `slmgr /dlv`, which is 1000.

b) looking at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769827/sysprep-fails-after-you-remove-or-update-windows-store-apps-that-inclu for provisioned M$ Store apps removed or updated. None were removed or updated.

c) Running a PowerShell command `Get-AppxPackage -AllUser | Where PackageFullName -eq 89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.8.1.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w| Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers` did not help.

d) Removing default pre-installed Appx for all users as per https://www.thewindowsclub.com/erase-default-preinstalled-modern-apps-windows-8 with Powershell-as-admin commands `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers` followed by 'Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online` which did not help.

[Windows 8.1 Enterprise Sysprep Error](https://superuser.com/questions/659552/windows-8-1-enterprise-sysprep-error) suggested other things I have not done above:

e) *Don't upgrade*. It's not an upgrade, it's a brand new install.

f) *Delete any other user account, use only Administrator*. There are no other accounts other than Administrator.

g) *Don't update Modern apps*. No Modern apps are updated. The LAN is disconnected during install to prevent this.

h) *If you need to add any other settings please use the answer file settings.* No other settings are added.

i) *Delete the Registry item DWORD HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade*. No such item found.

j) *Delete folders c:\windows.old and the c:\Windows~BT*. No such folders found.

k) Following a Reddit tip https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/5gpk9u/sysprep_was_not_able_to_validate_your_windows/, I checked C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\StateRepository-Machine.srd  with sqlitebrowser3. No users who should not exist were found in the user and userpackage tables.

l) https://wibier.me/sysprep-not-able-validate-windows-installation/ suggested checking to make sure the OD was no labeled as an upgrade (even though it isn't an upgrade) but there was no REG_DWORD 'Upgrade' key found in the Registry at In the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\ node.

m) As per the suggestion of [Origami](https://superuser.com/users/722170/origami) below, I checked BitLocker with `manage-bde -status` . It was on, so I ran a PowerShell command as Administrator in another window `Disable-Bitlocker –MountPoint ‘C:’` and kept checking with  `manage-bde -status` in another window, until it showed C: was unencrypted. Then, also as per that suggestion, I followed http://computer-help-please.blogspot.com/2016/01/sysprep-error-windows-81-sysprep.html, and in Powershell opened as Administrator, ran `Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage` then went to the Windows 10 Modern menu, selected every live tile, and marked them to turn them off. Also made sure the PC did not connect to a LAN, either Ethernet or WiFi. Made sure HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\SysprepStatus values for cleanupstate and generalizationstate matched the image shown at http://computer-help-please.blogspot.com/2016/01/sysprep-error-windows-81-sysprep.html. Chose Sysprep again with Generalize selected, it rebooted, and it failed again, returning me to the Administrator screen.

FYI, the Modern apps menu shows several tiles with icons for Calendar, Mail, Xbox, Photos, Microsoft Store, Edge, Skype, OneNote, My Office, Movies and TV, Calculator, Groove Music, and Maps, whereas on the previous reboot all it showed was the down-arrow icon.

https://theitbros.com/sysprep-was-not-able-to-validate-your-windows-installation/ suggested two more approaches to investigate:

n) looking for *Error  SYSPRP Package SomeAppName_1.2.3.500_x64__8we4y23f8b4ws was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image*. However, there are no other users at this point besides Administrator, and no other packages are iinstalled.

o)  looking for *Error  0x0f0036  SYSPRP spopk.dll:: Sysprep will not run on an upgraded OS. You can only run Sysprep on a custom (clean) install version of Windows*. That error did not appear and this was a clean install.

Another relevant possibility was found at [Sysprepping an offline Windows 10 system?](https://superuser.com/questions/1249772/sysprepping-an-offline-windows-10-system)

p) *Bring up a Administrator's cmd prompt, go to the oobe folder and manually run msoobe*. This runs through the OOBE and then it gets to "Just a moment..."; the throbber spins over over an hour before I killed it.

I eagerly await other suggestions on how to resolve this besides https://xkcd.com/2083 or https://youtu.be/48vQ5q2b0rs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encountered a similar issue and had to remove some of Windows 10 built-in apps.

```
%WINDIR%\System32\Sysprep\Panther\setuperr.log
```

should tell you which apps you need to remove.

You can uninstall it manually from

> Settings > Apps > Uninstall

or by running a Powershell script.

Answer (score 2):

Today I just had to make an image with Sysprep and Acronis True Image 2017 New Generation. For the first time, I also got the error: "*Sysprep was not able to validate your Windows installation*" on Windows version 1803 and 1903,  with many error packages.

Let me show you how to overcome it to successfully create a Windows image with Acronis:

1. Open your Windows Setting and Search 'reset this pc' so click 'Get Started', so you will get the notification that you want or not to reset 'document and app or keep document', so I choose 'reset document and app' and Windows will restart automatically.
2. Second, you will show the first page just like after installing new Windows, and continue setting that Windows setting until you finish and show the desktop.
3. Third, and open the drive where the Windows folder is located and search "sysprep" ex: `C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep` and get the sysprep.exe. Open it → Run As Administrator.
   a. Enter System Out-Of-Box-Experience (OOBE)
   b. Check 'Generalize'
   c. And choose Shutdown Option; Reboot

TADAAAA!1!1! I can run backup Windows with Acronis and Sysprep now.

Comment: What do you mean by "Ceklis Generalize"?

Comment: on the window sysprep there is a check box and you just choose the "Generalize"

Comment: I edited your answer to reflect that.

Comment: thank's dude, love you

Answer (score 0):

After install 1809, you need to unlock BitLocker encryption firstly.

Go to Control Panel to turn off BitLocker. It will take a little time for decryption.

[image]

Then refer to the following article for the other error in log.

http://computer-help-please.blogspot.com/2016/01/sysprep-error-windows-81-sysprep.html

Comment: This _did not work_. See item m) above.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from uninstalling apps that only single users have (autodownloaded) with `get-appxpackage -allusers *appname* | remove-appxpackage -allusers`, which works in 1809 now, I have to turn on bitlocker, then turn off bitlocker.  Sysprep frequently thinks bitlocker is enabled when it's not.  This is on a new Dell laptop.

Answer (score -1):

I tried many of these fixes and it did not apply or work. I simply changed my timezone so that the time was correct and I was able to run sysprep. Seems too simple to have worked, but it's been the answer on 2 different machines so far.